# Heap: determine a leaf in C++

Tags: c++, heap

this explanation is little bit confuse me about the determination of a leaf in a heap

"Notice how we can detect whether or not a node in the heap is a leaf. If the number of items in the heap is at least n, but less than 2*n+1, then the node with subscript n is a leaf on this binary tree."

for example:

val   |5|3|4|2|

ind |0|1|2|3|

so there are 4 element in the array, when i trickle down to element 2, i should stop right ?

because from the equation 2*n + 1, mean the root is 2*root+1 and has to be less than the total node, right?

thank you!

Comment: Your question is missing a lot of background.  What is a _"heap"_ for example.  The question as posed assumes we know of only one possible heap implementation - there are many.

Comment: @RichardCritten [What, you have never seen Fraggle Rock?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Fraggle_Rock_characters#Marjory_the_Trash_Heap)

Answer (score 1):

```
n = 0  Is the heap at least n?      Yes
       Is the heap less than 2*n+1? No
n = 1  Is the heap at least n?      Yes
       Is the heap less than 2*n+1? No
n = 2  Is the heap at least n?      Yes
       Is the heap less than 2*n+1? Yes
```

By induction you can tell that everything after `n=2` is a leaf node as well. Thinking about this in reverse, if you find the parent of the last node, you will know that every element following is a leaf node. Therefore, the last non-leaf node is index `(3-1)/2 = 1`.

Comment: i was thinking like if there are four nodes in a heap. at the level 2, node #1 will not be a leaf since 2*1+1 = 3 which is < 4. so node #1 is not a leaf. but for node #2, on the same level, 2*2+1 = 5 which i > 4. so node #2 is a leaf since there is no node #5 in the heap. similar with node #3.